# How would Annie's going underground prove anything?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I'm wondering how Annie's going underground (in episode 23) would prove she wasn't the Female Titan? Also, was her reason for not going there only because she knew it was a trap, or did she have another reason as well? It feels like I have missed something..

Comment: one possible reason is, she knew it was a trap.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that Mikasa was with them. Were it only Armin and Eren, Annie might not be that afraid of going underground. Annie knows that in human combat, Mikasa can match her if not best her. The only way for her to defeat Mikasa and take Eren with her is for her not to go underground. Going underground will prevent her from transforming, not because of the dark, but because if she transform there, she will be trapped in the tunnel, preventing her from moving. Being unable to move will cause not only:

1. her identity as the female titan be exposed
2. be captured by the Scouting Legion
3. failing her mission of capturing Eren alive

that's why.

Comment: A well written answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Annie's titan transformation was her main weapon. If indeed she was the Female Titan, she wouldn't want to go underground because that would put her at a huge disadvantage (she wouldn't be able to properly transform in such a small space).

Answer (score 1):

**Warning : possible spoilers from the manga**

The power of the titans comes from light. So, during the night, they lose their power and become inactive or, at least, less vigorous than during the day.

So, Annie may have feared that she would be unable to transform in the dark or to fight well against Mikasa and Eren.

Comment: i think that doesn't apply to titan like, Eren,Annie and other who can turn them into titan, because there is chapter where titan attacking at night.

Comment: @mirroroftruth It may be less effective on them but I think it still applies since Annie, in her crystal thing, is guarded underground

Comment: less effective can be the reason but not "unable" and underground provide more security, doesn't allow full transformation and can be confined, so will be less difficult to control.

Comment: Does this mean that confined spaces can prevent the full transformation? It seems like the light might play a role here, since they could've lure Annie to any other confined space (such as a regular house) if it was the space itself preventing the transformation..

Comment: @thosetinydreams confined place like underground where a lot of work it required to break and IIRC in manga someone did transform at night to keep promise.

Comment: @mirroroftruth Thanks for the clarification! I definitely need to read the manga now :)